# All queries combined using a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT

Tags: sql, union

Simple Union query resulting in the error (All queries combined using a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator must have an equal number of expressions in their target lists.). I double checked the columns and everything looks good. What other reason(s) would cause this resulting error?

```
select OpportunityOwner, RecordType, ForecastCategory, CaseSafeOppID, date, [Fiscal Qtr], CloseDate,
MasterLicenseAmt, TrueMCVEst, MasterLicenseAmt + TrueMCVEst "Total $"
from ds_adhoc_sops.Pipe.DailyLicMCV

union

select OpportunityOwner, RecordType, ForecastCategory, CaseSafeOppID, date, [Fiscal Qtr], CloseDate
MasterLicenseAmt, TrueMCVEst, MasterLicenseAmt + TrueMCVEst "Total $"
from ds_adhoc_sops.Pipe.QTRLicMcvWL
;
```

Thank you

Comment: Hi, please share the error message, to make it easier to figure out what the issue is.

Comment: Hi there and thanks for responding, as per my initial post, the error message is "All queries combined using a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator must have an equal number of expressions in their target lists."

Comment: You have a missing comma after `CloseDate` in the second query

Comment: There's a missing comma after `ClosedDate` in the second subquery, resulting in 9 columns, not 10 like in the first subquery.

Comment: Oh boy... sorry for wasting your time. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a comma in the second part of the union statement, therefore the column size is different.

Try this:

```
select OpportunityOwner, RecordType, ForecastCategory, CaseSafeOppID, date, [Fiscal Qtr], CloseDate,
    MasterLicenseAmt, TrueMCVEst, MasterLicenseAmt + TrueMCVEst "Total $"
    from ds_adhoc_sops.Pipe.DailyLicMCV

union

select OpportunityOwner, RecordType, ForecastCategory, CaseSafeOppID, date, [Fiscal Qtr], CloseDate,
MasterLicenseAmt, TrueMCVEst, MasterLicenseAmt + TrueMCVEst "Total $"
from ds_adhoc_sops.Pipe.QTRLicMcvWL
;
```

Comment: Thank you, and the others who answered as well. Simple syntax overlook on my part. Just to make things clearer for others, can you please change your answer from "Colon" to "Comma"?